# jQuery Get / Set on input box value disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the value inputted/selected to the search bar to stay displaying underneath it, within "Displaying 5 of 14 palettes for..."

Here's [the link](http://scm.ulster.ac.uk/~B00553636/test/mp2/app.php) to the live prototype I've use.

The get set function I've used below, which allows me to do this, however this seems to appear just before the API kicks in, and disappear once the results load, any ideas why?

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#button").click(function(event) {

      var un = $('#nobg').val();

      greeting = un;

      $("#displayUserName").text(greeting);

    });

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send the search query the page is reloaded - the value that was entered into the input field is gone.  You'll need to have the search function return that value in some way - and either grab it with JavaScript and put it back into the div, or output it in the proper place via php.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your JS code gets executed correctly, but then your form gets submitted and causes the page to reload.

Try sticking a event.preventDefault() in there, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#button").click(function(event) {

      event.preventDefault();

      var un = $('#nobg').val();

      greeting = un;

      $("#displayUserName").text(greeting);

    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I added that and it breaks the search functionality of the button - it doesn't search for any results

Comment: Ah, okay, so you want to do the search with an actual page refresh.